# Is it safe to assume static variables never get cleared?

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

I've had users reporting random crashes within an application, particularly when switching between other apps. Unfortunately for the time being, I am unable to replicate the crash or get hold of the crash logs. Within my iOS application, I have a static class where I store variable which I refer to throughout the app - I have a hunch that this is what is causing the issue:

```
namespace DemoApp.BusinessLogic
{
    public static class AppController
    {
        public static string WebServiceURL { get; set; }
        public static int UserId { get; set; }
        public static User User { get; set; }
        //...
    }
}
```

The values for these are initiated when the user first logs into the app. My understanding was that static references are never cleared by ARC, is this correct? Am I safe to assume that these values never be cleared until the application is closed?

I could replace these static values to references to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
namespace DemoApp.BusinessLogic
{
    public static class AppController
    {
        public static string WebServiceURL { 
            get { 
                return NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("WebServiceURL"); 
            } 
            set { 
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, "WebServiceURL"); 
            }
        }

        public static string UserId { 
            get { 
                return NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("UserId"); 
            } 
            set { 
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, "UserId"); 
            }
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Is this a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that static references are never cleared by ARC, is this correct?

Yes, this is correct. ARC will not clear your static variables, unless they are `weak` and the object that they reference has no other references.

> I could replace these static values to references to `NSUserDefaults`. Is this a better way of doing things?

This comparison is not an apples-to-apples, because the value in `NSUserDefaults` will survive closing the application and even powering down the device, while a `static` would have to be initialized on start-up. If persisting `WebServiceURL` and `UserId` across different runs is desirable, then `NSUserDefaults` is a good approach; otherwise, a `static` is good enough.

Comment: Just to clarify - in the above example, I set AppController.User to a new User object in the login process. I then call on it in certain parts of code, so AppController.User.FirstName for example. As I don't reference this AppController.User object anywhere else, does that make it weak and therefore subject to being cleared?

Comment: @Joseph The only way to make a variable weak is adding the `weak` keyword in its declaration. The way you use a variable does not change its strong/weak designation.